# Is there a way to get elevation in leaflet

Tags: jquery, leaflet, altitude

I need find evelation value in leaflet using lat and lng paramaters. I dont want use google elevation. Is there any way for this ?

I am trying build sometihng like that [image: what i wnat]

I tried this but its not working : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302190/getting-elevation-data-in-leaflet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way.

> Google Elevation API

Just this api giving elevation but it is paid. 5 usd per 1000 request.

Comment: Your response does not answer the question. The question specifically says Google Elevation is not wanted.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33568849)